# swing mappanel map refresh

Tags: java, swing, jtree, openstreetmap

Currently I am working on a swing application, consisting of a frame with splitpanel. In the left panel I have a jtree, listing all the countries in the world, in the right panel I have an OpenStreetMap, showing a map at startup (which works). 
The nodes of the jtree are linked to the valueChanged(..) event handler:

```
/** Required by TreeSelectionListener interface. */
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    mapPanel = drawOpenStreetMap(45, 65, 12);
    mapPanel.repaint();
    repaint();
    splitPane.repaint();
    repaint();
    updateUI();
}

MapPanel drawOpenStreetMap(double lon, double lat, int zoom) {
    mapPanel = new MapPanel(); // just a JPanel extension, add to any swing/awt container
    mapPanel.setZoom(zoom); // set some zoom level (1-18 are valid)
    Point position = mapPanel.computePosition(new Point2D.Double(lon, lat));
    mapPanel.setCenterPosition(position); // sets to the computed position
    mapPanel.repaint(); // if already visible trigger a repaint here
    return mapPanel;
}
```

The valueChanged method gets called on clicking on a jtree node and the drawOpenStreetMap get called indeed and I expected the map to update and show a new location. But nothing changes. The map created at startup remains visible unaltered. The code of the valueChange method shows a number of repaint() calls etc. I have tried, to no avail.

Here is a pointer to the [MapPanel](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/DataExtractionOSM/src/net/osmand/swing/MapPanel.java?name=HEAD) source code.

Would be greatful if somebody could tell me how to update the map. Thanks in advance!

Postscript: I refered to the wrong MapPanel; it must be [this one](http://mappanel.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mappanel/com.roots.map/src/com/roots/map/MapPanel.java?revision=37&view=markup).

Comment: random repaints rarely help :-) And never call updateUI: it's _not_ meant to be used in application code (instead, it's used internally when changing the LAF)

Comment: @kleopatra - probably, but I read this first in the java tutorial and there they do use painting in application code. To be honest, I never understood that painting business properly :)

Comment: Was talking about this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't add the MapPanel instance you created to the parent container like `SplitPanel` in the `valueChanged()` methods.

When `valueChanged()` method invoked, you call `drawOpenStreetMap()` method to create a `MapPanel` instance, however, you didn't add it to the `SplitPanel`. That's why the new location of map didn't appear. Perhaps you need to insert the code like the following:

```
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    mapPanel = drawOpenStreetMap(45, 65, 12);
    rightPanel.add(mapPanel); // rightPanel is the panel in the right side of split pane.
    ...
```

Comment: That was indeed the solution, thanks a ton!! I would have thought that it would be enough to link the mappanel to the rightpanel only once in the constructor and that some update/repaint/whatever, would be called for to handle events. But this works.

Comment: +1 for spotting :-) After the add, you'll have to call revalidate to trigger the update of the layout. @jhulst If it's really needed to create a _new_ mapPanel, you'll want to remove the old before adding the new. Would be easier if the MapPanel had api to update the location ... does it?